# Is there a well-designed, maintained RSS-parsing library for Java?

Tags: java, rss

I know this question has been asked before, but that was several years ago, and of the two answers, [Rome](http://rome.dev.java.net/) and [Abdera](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ABDERA/Getting+Started), the first no-longer seems to be maintained (there aren't even any download links on the website, nor can I find documentation).  The latter also appears rather complicated, and neither appears up to contemporary standards of Java library design.

Are there any new alternatives out there that are well designed, and well maintained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found [HorroRSS](http://code.google.com/p/horrorss/), which is exactly what I was hoping for.  Its simple, easy to use, and appears robust.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not know of any library, but, that said, seeing as RSS is an XML format you should be able to roll your own using SAX/JAXB/DOM. Which one to use depends on whether you wan ease of integration with Java ([JAXB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing.html)) or speed ([SAX](http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html#6.1.2)). There is a middle ground in [DOM](http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html#6.1.1).

RSS is not a complicated format so I think you could just develop the features you need as you come across them and it'll be faster (and the skills you learn more transferable) than exhaustice searching for a library if one cannot be found easily.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this class [RSSDigester](http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/testapidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/digester/rss/package-summary.html). It might help, I don't realy have the time to investigate it right now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

RSS reading hasn't really needed changing for some time. ROME really is quite nice, and as far as fetching it you can get it from http://download.java.net/maven/2/rome/.